# contains() with Generic Type

Tags: java

I need to convert the method "contains()"

```
public boolean contains(List<Integer> list, int value){
    for (int i : list) {
        if(i == value)
          return true;
```

into a method that can search for every datatype but i dont really know how to do it.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Search<T> {
    public boolean contains(List<T> list, T value){
        for ( T i : list) {
            if(i == value)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt so far but i dont know if this is all i have to do or not.
I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: One line method, `return list.contains(value);`

Comment: The amount of lines inside the code has to stay the same.

Comment: Then change `i == value` to `i.equals(value)`

Comment: Alright, thank you very much :)

Comment: Because you use generic type, please use `.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: to also note you should be comparing to a `T` witness value if you want it to work for all list types. Though why you wouldn't just use `List#contains` is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a method in `List<T>` that does that, `List<T>::contains`.

If you want to implement your own there are two ways to do it:

1. Same instance:

Here if the equals method hasn't been overridden it will return `true` if they are literally the same instance in memory.

```
public <T> boolean contains(List<T> list, T object){
    for( T t : list){
        if(t.equals(object))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2. Similar objects

Here you are forcing your `T` class to implement the `Comparable` interface, which contains a `compareTo(o : Object)` that returns 0 if they are similar.

```
public <T extends Comparable> boolean contains(List<T> list, T object){
    for( T t : list){
        if(t.compareTo(object) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `equals` instead of `==`

```
import java.util.List;

public class Search<T> {
    public boolean contains(List<T> list, T value){
        for ( T i : list) {
            if(i.equals(value))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```